# Sharing GCP Source repository for the Cloud build of second project

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I've been searching through similar questions but none of them was quite answered.

I have 2 GCP Projects, Project A is running one environment and has connected Bitbucket, which is cloned into Source Repository. Then I want to run Cloud Build from project B with a repository from project A.

First of all, I gave Source Repository Administrator permission to project-B@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com on project A.

This still doesn't allow me to create triggers because I can't list connected repositories on project B, even though it has permissions. However, I successfully created these triggers via Terraform where I followed the basic approach of creating triggers and defined trigger_teplate like this:

```html
  trigger_template {
    project_id  = "ProjectA"
    branch_name = "dev"
    repo_name   = "bitbucket_org_reponame"
  }
```

After applying the terraform, it created the trigger and I was able to run it manually and it worked, however, it still shows that repositories are not connected. This means that the trigger can't run automatically and for manual invocation, I always have to write down the branch which I want to use.

This is quite inconvenient for me, did I miss something? Some permissions that I need to add, is it still impossible even when this works partially?

Comment: The steps that you follow seem correct and is perhaps a product limitation. You can consider opening an issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Also, from what I can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access#grant_viewing_permissions_across_a_project) what you are trying to do is theoretically possible.

Comment: In summary, you want to catch the "push event" of the code stored in project A, to automatically trigger the Cloud Build in project B, correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, that would be one of my desired workflows. But I also want to catch tag event, I would prefer If it could be possible to work with the repository from another project same way as if it's in a given project.

Comment: Did you try to add in your trigger_template the entry `project_id = "ProjectA"`?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually doing this, forgot to mention in my code snippet, I'll edit it in. Thanks